# Name of the slickgrid tooltip class

Tags: slickgrid

> I want to give some styling to my slick grid tool-tip. I can not figure out the name of the class which contains tool-tip text.

Comment: if you are using `Slick.AutoTooltips`, it is not adding any class to produce the tool-tip text but just adding the `title` property when the column is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Default is the native (browser) tooltip that has no class (it can't be styled).
However jQueryUI has a tooltip class that can be used to upgrade the basic tooltip: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default

just adding `$( document ).tooltip();` somewhere in the page code will turn all tooltips on the page into jQueryUI tooltips.

for extra styling, pass an option: `$( document ).tooltip( { tooltipClass: "myCssClss" } );` (though I haven't actually tried this!)